# SQL Table Join, Query Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I am use this query for join table, and it works but return only 1 value and I want color wise data not all data. Here is my Query and its **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9a92/2/0)**

```
  SELECT *,
         (SELECT pname
            FROM tbl_product
           WHERE id = tbl_productcolor.pid
          ) as productname,
         (SELECT image
            FROM tbl_product
           WHERE id = tbl_productcolor.pid
          ) as image
    FROM tbl_productcolor
   WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

And Here Is My Two Table

**tbl_product**

```
id      category        pcode       pname       image
-----------------------------------------------------
1       cat1            567         product1    img1.jpg
2       cat2            544         product2    img2.jpg
3       cat3            5665        product3    img3.jpg
4       cat1            5665        t1          img4.jpg
5       cat1            567         t5          img5.jpg
6       cat3            75          t8          img6.jpg
7       cat4            12          name        img7.jpg
```

**tbl_productcolor**

```
    id          pid         color
-----------------------------
1           1           Black (79)
2           1           Grey (205)
3           1           Green (69)
4           1           Blue (89)
5           1           Purple (14)
6           1           Yellow (31)
7           1           Brown (124)
8           1           Beige (95)
9           1           Cream (164)
10          1           White (09)
11          2           Multi-coloured (113)
12          2           Black (79)
13          3           Pattern (84)
14          3           Metallic (48)
15          3           Black (79)
16          3           Orange (29)
17          3           Beige (95)
18          4           Green (69)
19          4           Red (33)
20          4           Yellow (31)
21          4           Brown (124)
22          4           Beige (95)
23          4           White (09)
24          5           Black (79)
25          5           Green (69)
26          5           Purple (14)
27          5           Red (33)
28          6           Metallic (48)
29          6           Black (79)
30          6           Grey (205)
31          6           Green (69)
32          6           Purple (14)
33          6           Pink (20)
34          6           Red (33)
35          7           Pattern (84)
36          7           Multi-coloured (113)
37          7           Metallic (48)
38          7           Black (79)
39          7           Grey (205)
40          7           Green (69)
41          7           Blue (89)
42          7           Purple (14)
43          7           Pink (20)
44          7           Red (33)
45          7           Orange (29)
46          7           Yellow (31)
47          7           Brown (124)
48          7           Beige (95)
49          7           Cream (164)
50          7           White (09)
```

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Comment: Query produces expected result.  What were you trying for?

Comment: @BrijRajSingh its return only one value in place of return all value from tbl_productcolor where id of tbl_product match in tbl_productcolor's pid

Comment: Looks like one row to me.

Comment: may be he needs to get all the products along with their productcolor, using a join.

Comment: the query you have written isn't doing what you are anyways asking for, now lets try

Comment: Remove where clause `where id=1`

Comment: select *,(select pname from tbl_product where id=tbl_productcolor.pid)as productname,(select image from tbl_product where id=tbl_productcolor.pid)as image FROM tbl_productcolor order by id asc ;

Comment: hmm @BrijRajSingh thanks for helping me, i post fiddle link, you can try there.

Comment: i tried it works with this query select *,(select pname from tbl_product where id=tbl_productcolor.pid)as productname,(select image from tbl_product where id=tbl_productcolor.pid)as image FROM tbl_productcolor order by id asc ;

Comment: I want that output should display, color wise data. If selected color is black, then display all data product where color is black

Comment: Could you add the output that you want to your question, same as the sample table?

Comment: @GoatCO See, I have two table as I declare above. Now there are some product in product table with color like, red, black, yellow etc. and other table with same color value like red, black and yellow. now I want that if I select black color from color table, then it should show all value with color is black from product table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got it right you need to normalize `tbl_productcolor` table to make your Life a little bit easier.

You should divide your table in two:

```
tbl_productcolor

id          pid      color_id
-----------------------------
1           1        1   
29          6        1
2           1        2
30          6        2
```

and

```
tbl_colors

id   name
----------------------
1    Black (79)
2    Grey (205)
```

For your current structure there is a query I guess you need:

```
select 
C1.ID,
C1.PID,
c1.color,
p.pname,
p.image 
FROM tbl_productcolor C1 
JOIN tbl_productcolor C2 ON C1.Color=C2.Color AND C2.ID=1
JOIN tbl_product p ON C1.PID=p.ID

order by p.id asc ;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9a92/45)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

What you want exactly.(Output)?
If you remove (where id=1) then you get all result;

```
SELECT prdc.id, 
       prdc.pid, 
       prdc.color, 
       pr.pname, 
       pr.image 
FROM   tbl_productcolor prdc 
       INNER JOIN tbl_productcolor prd 
               ON prdc.color = prd.color 
                  AND prd.id = 2 
       INNER JOIN tbl_product pr 
               ON prdc.pid = pr.id;
```

you can use this query it should be work.

Comment: I don't want all result, I want i.e color wise data by joining table.

Comment: I want that output should display, color wise data. If selected color is black, then display all data product where color is black

Comment: OK all the same color id is diffrent.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tbl_product 
where id in (select pid 
    from tbl_productcolor 
    where color="Black (79)")
```

Comment: I want that output should display, color wise data. If selected color is black, then display all data product where color is black

Comment: select * from tbl_product where id in (select pid from tbl_productcolor where color="Black (79)")

Answer (score 0):

You can use following

```
SELECT P.Id, 
       PC.Id AS ColorId, 
       PC.color
FROM tbl_product P
INNER JOIN tbl_productcolor PC 
        ON P.Id=PC.PId
WHERE PC.Color='Black (79)'
```

You can also use child table id or color code name.